# In a graph, how to calculate sum of all nodes which a node can reach efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a directed graph, with weight assigned to every node.
Start from any node A, there will be a set of nodes which could be reached from A.
Define SUM as total weight of this set.

Question: 
How to calculate SUM for every node in this graph efficiently?
The graph may contain millions of nodes.

Update 1:
The graph data structure is composed of the set of start nodes, and each node have a set of point-to nodes.

What I tried:
Calculate the descendants of every node recursively, and calculate the SUM according to descendant set. This recursion is very inefficient since I have to do set union, uteration operation for a lot of times. Further, I tried to cache the descendant set at each node. However, it easily runs out of memory.
So, is there any other solution?

Update 2:
Example graph, edges are all directed, upper nodes points to lower nodes
[image: Sample Graph]
Result should be
    SUM(1)=55
    SUM(2)=35
    SUM(3)=41
    SUM(4)=19
    SUM(5)=22
    SUM(6)=25
    ...

Comment: so each the sum for a given node is the sum of the weights of all nodes in that connected component which contains that node?

Comment: @Dan D. Yes, sorry I didn't notice your reply in time...

Comment: Are there any additional assumptions? E.g. O(1) size for the set of point-to nodes?

Comment: Also, how do you want this algorithm to be efficient? You mentioned memory. Maybe you want to optimize cache misses instead of just running time?

Comment: @Matthijs Wessels No other assumptions of the graph. Actually, I am expecting an algorithm with a lower complexity level than my recursion solution.

Answer (score 10):

Find the SCC's of the graph (Tarjan's algorithm, or a double DFS run).

For each SCC calculate the sum of it's node weights, denote this value by PARTIAL-SUM.

Iterate over the SCC's in reverse topological order; for every node in each SCC, its SUM will be the sum of all the SUM values of adjacent SCC's plus it's own PARTIAL-SUM value.

Linear running time `O(E+V)` since finding SCC's is linear, topological sort is linear, and the summation is linear since we visit each SCC at most once and each branch at most once.

**EDIT**

As was pointed out in the comments by tzkuzzy parallel paths pose a problem. That is easily solved by a simple DFS run on the SCC graph. On any cross-edge we simply take the already visited node up the DFS tree until we reach a not-fully-searched parent, this pair of nodes (the visited on the bottom, and the ancestor) has two distinct paths between them, we make a list for each node of such descendants, and on summation merely subtract their PARTIAL-SUM value.

So if:

```
 u
/ \
\ /
 w
```

Our DFS will pick up the cross edge connecting from a child node of `u` to `w`, and trace back to `u` (for those familiar with the typical DFS taught in schools the easiest explanation is that `u` is characterised as the first grey ancestor of `w`), so we add `w` to the list we maintain on `u`.

Then when we sum each SCC's adjacent SCC's as described, we add an extra step where we loop over the list mentioned and simply subtract PARTIAL-SUM values.

The DFS itself is still linear. Backtracking from a node to an ancestor can be linear if we cache the results (that way we don't traverse the same edge more than once). And the additional work in the summation is at most `O(V)`, so we haven't changed the running time.

**EDIT**

Inclusion-exclusion makes this more difficult than I first thought. This solution isn't complete and doesn't work. A simple BFS for each node is more expensive but easier and will work.

Comment: SCC is Strongly Connected Component.

Comment: Er, don't you have to sum over all SCCs that are ordered below (as opposed to adjacent to) the SCC you're looking at?

Comment: @tskuzzy, why would you want that? If it's ordered below but not adjacent then it's not reachable, and shouldn't be included.

Comment: @davin: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. But consider `1 -> 2 -> 3`. Your SCCs are just the nodes themselves. So for the node of value `1`, you want to sum all nodes ordered below and including itself: `1+2+3`. If you just sum adjacent ones, you'd just get `1+2`.

Comment: @tskuzzy, you are indeed misunderstanding. `3` will have SUM `3`, `2` will have SUM `2+3=5` and finally `1` will have SUM `1+5=6`

Comment: @davin: Oh I see, I would have called that PARTIAL_SUM and PARTIAL_SUM called `SCC_SUM` or something like that xD. Anywho, don't you double count then? If you had the paths `1 -> 2 -> 4` and `1 -> 3 -> 5`. Your SUM for `2` would be `2+5=7` and SUM for `3` would be `3+5=8`. And then your SUM for `1` would be `1+7+8=16` when it should be `1+2+3+5=11`.

Comment: @tskuzzy, where are you getting those sums? Do you know what topological order is? You're bringing counter examples that don't use my algorithm.

Comment: @davin: Sorry I had a typo. I meant `1 -> 2 -> 4` and `1 -> 3 -> 4`. A topological ordering would be `1,2,3,4`, which after reversing is `4,3,2,1`. Again, each SCC is just 1 node. So we start with 4, whose SUM is just `4`. 3's SUM is `3+SUM(4)=7`. 2's SUM is `2+4=6`. 1's SUM is `1+SUM(2)+SUM(3)=1+6+7=14`. I'm denoting the SUM of the node w/ value N as SUM(N).

Comment: @davin I think tskuzzy's example is good. It seems to be more complicated.

Comment: @tskuzzy Thank you for discussion. Your example is common in my graph.

Comment: Why do we need to find SCCs here instead of just doing a simple DFS or BFS?

Comment: @davin I am not clear sure about your patched solution. As the sample graph I added in the question, will node 8 be stored in all its ancestors?

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer is a nice idea but inclusion-exclusion of intersecting subtrees is very difficult to solve (something I think your recursive approach will suffer from as well). Come to think of it, I'm beginning to doubt if there even exists a substructure of optimality in this problem that would lend to a dynamic programming solution...

I will propose a much simpler (albeit less efficient) solution:

For each node, run a BFS/DFS and sum the values of all nodes encountered. It'll run in `O(V)` space and `O(V(E+V)) = O(EV)` time, but is *super* simple to implement and doesn't need to be recursive.

You can optimise by finding the SCC graph and instead of performing the BFS/DFS on every node do so once for every SCC. This may increase running time by a huge factor if the graph is "cliquey".

Comment: I am afraid there are not many SCCs in the graph. I am still trying to find a way that do not need do BFS/DFS on so many nodes. For the real graph I need to process, E and V are both up to 1 million, O(EV) is not accepatble I think. Thank you all the same :)

Comment: Luckily, this program can be distributed on a many-core server. And the runtime is acceptable now.